# How to get FFplay to stop looping last audio packet?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to get FFplay to simply stop (pause) on the last image when playing through.

The default behavior for FFplay appears to use the `-loops` perimeter, which causes the last audio packet to be looped - even though the image appears in a paused state.

Is there a way to also stop playing audio on end of file?

Answer (score 1):

One can use `-autoexit` to exit after playing the file. More info here: https://ffmpeg.org/ffplay-all.html#Advanced-options

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your audio stream is shorter then your video stream. You can use `ffprobe -show_streams -print_format json -v quiet << INPUT FILE >>` and look for the duration length of each stream.

I'm not sure if you can 'loop' the audio input, but you may concatenate(?) the audio input. I can give you a complex `filter_complex` and `concat` filter example to use with `ffplay`, yet what I really think you should do is re-encode the input streams to be on the same length.

`ffmpeg -i << INPUT >> -filter_complex "[0:0]fifo[v];[0:1]fifo[a];[v][a][a][a][a]concat=n=4:v=1:a=4[v_out][a_out]" -map "[v_out]" -map "[a_out]" -c:v libx264 -q:v 1 -g 30 -b:v 750k -c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 192k -q:a 1 -ar 44100 -shortest output.mp4`

Note: the `shortest` flag will stop the encoding when the shortest stream ends (in this case, probably will be the video sync we are concatenating the audio stream 4 times).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I think you misunderstood the question.   The default behavior for FFplay is to loop the last audio packet - which I DON'T want.  I would prefer to have the file stop playing any audio once the end of the file has been reached.... Give it a shot on your end.  Try playing a file that has audio in FFplay and scrub to the end of the file.  Once the end has been reached, the last audio packet should loop... I'm trying to find a way to stop this.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Oh really? ... Hmm - I'm just running a recent Zeranoe build on a Windows machine.  I'm seeing the same behavior across all of my Zeranoe builds that I've checked against so far.  Do you think it could be OS related?

Comment: not OS related is FFmpeg/FFplay is just the software, it must be configuration related. I knows nothing about compiling ffmpeg / ffplay on Windows machines (it's next to impossible in my mind). Try `./configure --help` maybe on osx/unix/linux machine to learn more about config flags